# Codeception Error : Call to undefined method Exception::getStatusCode()

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, codeception

When I run functional tests in Codeception in Laravel, every now and then I get the error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to undefined method Exception::getStatusCode()
```

These are my configs:

```
codeception.yml

actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=la51'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'root'
            populate: false
            cleanup: false
            reconnect: true
```

functional.suite.yml

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # add framework module here
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Asserts
        - Db
        - Laravel5
    config:
        Laravel5:
            cleanup: false
```

This is what I get in my terminal when I "codecept run":

```
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:la51 rubenbijker$ codecept run -vvv
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.1.3
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Acceptance Tests (0) ------------------------
Modules: PhpBrowser, \Helper\Acceptance
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------

Functional Tests (9) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules: \Helper\Functional, Asserts, Db, Laravel5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create a boat (AdminCreatesBoatCept)
Scenario:
* As an a guest
* I am on page ""


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to undefined method Exception::getStatusCode()      



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to undefined method Exception::getStatusCode()      


FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Call to undefined method Exception::getStatusCode() 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/la51/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:71
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:la51 rubenbijker$
```

I reported the issue with Codeception but they said it is a Laravel error so they can't help me. 
Is this caused because of an error in my code? Or by a misconfiguration between Codeception and Laravel?

Comment: It means that the exception thrown does not declare the method "getStatusCode"

Comment: What version of Codeception? It looks like a bug. Please report an issue at https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Comment: Codeception version 2.1.3. I will report it at github. Thanks.

Comment: I have reported this issue on github: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2466

Comment: I got an answer at github: 
"It is a Laravel error, because it happens in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/la51/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:71"
So I edited my question here with some more info about the error.

Comment: did you manually change your Handler? If so, can you please attach or post the contents ?

Comment: At least the default one, does not even have 71 Lines.

Comment: That is it! I had edited the Handler.php in order to run the old debugger. This caused the issue. When I revert the Handler.php back to the original state the issue is solved. You can post this as an answer if you would like to earn stack credits. Otherwise I'll create the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Codeception itself. It rather Looks like you have edited your Handler.php file manually. You have to fix the error in your changes ( Call to undefined method is quite clear ) or revert it to its orignal state.

Comment: You just saved me from suffering more pain! Thanks a lot!!